# SuiteScript 1.0 nlapiGetLineItemCount

Tags: javascript, netsuite, suitescript

I'm trying to use the `nlapiGetLineItemCount('purchaseorder');`command to get the number of lines of a Purchase Order. But it just return '-1' .

Is there something wrong with my code?

Thank you!

EDIT: I've also tried `nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');` and it's have the same behavior if there is something inexistent. Like this: `nlapiGetLineItemCount('trying_lines');`

### EDIT 2 : I'm trying to use it directly on CONSOLE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you tried in browser console you should be in "Edit Mode" (hit the record edit button or add &e=T to record url).

```
nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');
```

ClientScript 2.0

```
require(['N/currentRecord'], function (currentRecord) {
      console.log('getLineCount', currentRecord.get().getLineCount({sublistId: 'item'})
});
```

UserEvent 2.0 (in before load function)

```
function beforeLoad(context){ 
     log.debug('getLineCount', context.newRecord.getLineCount({sublistId: 'item'}))
}
```

Comment: That's it! I was not in edit mode. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Use `nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');` to get the number of line items in a purchase order.

Comment: I've tried it as well:

```nlapiGetLineItemCount('purchaseorder');
-1
nlapiGetLineItemCount('item');
-1```

Answer (score 0):

This call will only work in the context of: User Event, Client, or Workflow Action scripts. What script type are you trying to run it in?

In order to run this in the console and get a sensible result you'd have to be in the console opened on Purchase Order edit window.

Comment: Hi! I'm developing a new script that will block the rate for expense reports lines. Then, I'm testing each code block separately. So, I need to count the number of lines for that transaction, and then go ahead with the code.
I'm using SuiteScript 1 because i'm don't get into suitescript 2 also.
But, in case you have any suggestions using SS2.0, will be highly appreciated.
thank you!

Comment: BTW, I'm using it directly on CONSOLE. I didn't mentioned it yet. Sorry bout that.